# About the diagonalisaton of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I'm having problems with this diagonalisation for it seems "paradoxical" to me.

The matrix reads

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If I compute a simple Gauss reduction, I obtain the matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which is... already diagonal?

If $b = 1$ to say, I get the identity matrix, which is symmetric and diagonalizable.

If $b \neq 0$ in general, I can always divide the second row by $b$ and what I said above applies.

Yet if $b = 0$ well it is still a symmetric matrix hence it's diagonalizable.

Am I right here, or am I missing something?

I'm asking because my initial attack wasn't with a Gauss reduction. I got the characteristic polynomial as $p(\lambda) = (\lambda-1)^2(\lambda -b)$ whence when I compute the geometric multiplicity in the case of $b\neq 0$ (since I have a double $\lambda = 1$ eigenvalue, I get that the matrix, for $b \neq 0$ and $\lambda = 1$ reads

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which rank is two, hence the geometric multiplicity for $\lambda = 1$ and $b\neq 0$ is $1$, hence not diagonalizable.

I am surely missing something...

Thank you!

Comment: What do you think the row reduced matrix has to do with the original matrix in terms of its diagonalizability?  The question is about whether there exists a diagonal matrix $D$ and invertible matrix $S$ such that $A=SDS^{-1}$.  The row reduction of the matrix does not appear in that definition anywhere.  Indeed, the diagonalizability of the row reduction of a matrix and the original matrix itself need not be the same.

Comment: @JMoravitz But here without even computing a reduction, the given matrix could be already $D$ itself, whereas $S$ and $S^{-1}$ would be the identity matrices, and $A = D$. Or not?

Comment: @JMoravitz Gauss reduction does not preserve the eigenvalues, though.

Comment: $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is a non-diagonalizable matrix.  Make sure you fully understand what that means.  Make sure you understand why we know that there can not exist any matrices $S^{-1},D$ such that $A=SDS^{-1}$.  This is despite the fact that $A$ clearly can row reduce to the identity.  The row reduction of $A$ has **nothing** to do with the diagonalizability of $A$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand that matrix cannot be diagonalised because geometric multiplicity of $\lambda = 1$ is one, whereas algebraic multiplicity is two. Yet with Gauss we get the identity which is diagonalisable...

Comment: "*the given matrix could be already D itself*"  If the given matrix was actually diagonal... then sure.  The given matrix in your post is not diagonal however.  The row reduction of it might be but that is not the same thing as saying the original matrix is diagonal.  The row reduction of a matrix is not equal to the original matrix.  The row reduction of a matrix being diagonal is not the same thing as the original matrix being diagonal.  The row reduction of a matrix having a property does not mean the original matrix has that property too.

Comment: There do exist a few extremely limited properties that will be preserved when row reducing.  The rank of the matrix for example will be preserved when row reducing.  That is neither here nor there though when talking about diagonalization.  Row reducing is not an appropriate thing to consider here.  If you row reduce, then you are no longer looking at the original matrix... you are looking at something else... and that something else having or not having the property it can be diagonalized says *nothing* about whether the original could.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations! So about my case, it's not really always diagonalizable. After having calculated the polynomial, I find that $\lambda = 1$ is always double except for $b = 1$ which makes it triple. For $\lambda = 1$ and $b$ generic but not $1$ I get the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & b-1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Here I can apply Gauss reduction (or the minors criteria) and find that its rank is always two. Hence it's not diagonalizable. 

Instead if $b = 1$ the rank is two, and again not diagonalizable. 
Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has Gauss algorithm to do with diagonalization ?

By doing elementary row-operations, you are actually left multiplying your matrix with elementary matrices.

This means

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = E_1 E_2 ... E_n \begin{pmatrix}
1 & b & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$ where the $E_i$ are the elementary matrices corresponding to your row operations.

If you want to diagonalize, you need to find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & b & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} P$ is diagonal, which is different.

**EDIT:** From the row operations you have done you can conclude here is that $0$ is not an eigenvalue except if $b=0$,since the rank is preserved by row operations.

Comment: Thank you! So about my case, it's not diagonalizable. After having calculated the polynomial, I find that $\lambda = 1$ is always double except for $b = 1$ which makes it triple. For $\lambda = 1$ and $b$ generic but not $1$ I get the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & b-1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Here I can apply Gauss reduction (or the minors criteria) and find that its rank is always two. Hence it's not diagonalizable. 

Instead if $b = 1$ the rank is two, and again not diagonalizable. 
Right?

Comment: If you only have one eigenvalue, it's clear that it cannot be diagonalizable otherwise it would  have to be a diagonal matrix already. The only matrix similar to $\lambda I$ is $\lambda I$ itself.

Comment: I don't have one eigenvalue, I have three of them. $\lambda =1$ double and $\lambda = b$. If $b = 1$ then it's triple

Comment: If you have a triple eigenvalue for a $3\times3$ matrix then it means it's not diagonalizable, except if the matrix is already diagonal. For the generic case, you need to show that $M-I$ has rank ONE and that $M-bI$ has rank TWO to show that it's diagonalizable (or not). ($M$ is your original matrix)

Comment: Oh I got what you said now! Pardon. Anyway, if $b \neq 1$ the matrix is still not diagonalizable, right? I know I could compute things faster, perhaps without calculations but I also want to be sure about the mechanics!

Comment: Yes, since $M-I$ has rank $2$ this means the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $1$ has dimension $1$. To be diagonalizable you would have needed dimension $2$ and thus the rank of $M-I$ to be $1$, since the rank of $M-I$ and the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace always sum to $3$.